# Mix of line and scatter plots from pandas dataframe in a single plot using the tick frequency of the first plot only

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am wanting to compare data within a dataframe, plotting some of the data as lines, and other columns as scatter.  My actual data is a combination of model output and observations, I want the observations to be scatter, and the model to be lines.

The observations have a LOT of Nan values (most times steps do not have an observation).

This MWE duplicates the issue I'm having

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(40)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    "Time": date_list,
    "Chocolate": np.random.rand(40), 
    "Strawberry": np.random.rand(40), 
    "Fake Chocolate": np.random.rand(40), 
    "Fake Strawberry": np.random.rand(40), 
})
df.iloc[3,3] = np.nan

ax1 = df.plot(x = 'Time', y = ["Chocolate","Strawberry"])

ax1 = df.plot(x = 'Time', y = ["Chocolate","Strawberry"])
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x = 'Time', y = ['Fake Chocolate'], marker = '^', ax = ax1)
ax3 = df.plot.scatter(x = 'Time', y = ['Fake Strawberry'], marker = '*', ax = ax1, color = '#ff7f0e')
```

[image: example output]

I want to have the x-axis like in the first plot, so taking the style of the line plot where you don't have EVERY date trying to print in a tiny space.  How do I do this?

I am using `ax1.set` to set the x and y-axis labels.

and if I can sneak in a second question, why is it possible to do multiple lines using `y = []` but not possible for the scatter plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` to the end of your script and you will be fine.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(40)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    "Time": date_list,
    "Chocolate": np.random.rand(40), 
    "Strawberry": np.random.rand(40), 
    "Fake Chocolate": np.random.rand(40), 
    "Fake Strawberry": np.random.rand(40), 
})
df.iloc[3,3] = np.nan

ax1 = df.plot(x = 'Time', y = ["Chocolate","Strawberry"])

ax1 = df.plot(x = 'Time', y = ["Chocolate","Strawberry"])
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x = 'Time', y = ['Fake Chocolate'], marker = '^', ax = ax1)
ax3 = df.plot.scatter(x = 'Time', y = ['Fake Strawberry'], marker = '*', ax = ax1, color = '#ff7f0e')
plt.xticks(rotation=45);
```

[image]

[image]